# JavaScript TicTacToe instead of just adding a number at the end add it it to total

Tags: javascript

thanks for sharing interest in my question.

I've made a function which adds one point when someone wins in game (TicTacToe).

But there is one small problem [See Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEbFf.png)
When someone won the point should be added to the total and not be added in the line.

This is my JS and HTML which is used in the JS

```
function winnerScore() {
   if (document.winner == 1) {
       roundsInfo[3].innerHTML += 1;
   }
   else {
       roundInfo[5].innerHTML += 1;
   }
}
```

---

```
   <h1>Scores</h1>
            <table class="rounds-info">
                <tr>
                    <td><img width="15" height="15" alt="" title="" src="img/cross.jpg" />&nbsp;Speler 1</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img width="15" height="15" alt="" title="" src="img/circle.jpg" />&nbsp;Speler 2</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Aantal rondes</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending number to string. It will concatenate to the string as string.

You need to convert the string to number first and then add the number.

The following should do:

```
function winnerScore() {
   if (document.winner == 1) {
       roundsInfo[3].innerHTML =String(parseInt(roundsInfo[3].innerHTML) +1);
   }
   else {
       roundInfo[5].innerHTML = String(parseInt(roundsInfo[5].innerHTML) +1) ;
   }
}
```

Comment: Did it. btw you made a little mistake with the second roundsInfo, it says roundinfo instead of roundsInfo. Just so you know :)